# Webpack - stylelint watching instead of running once

Tags: webpack

I want to have stylelint ran after every change I make to an sass file (while webpack is `watch`ing). I tried to use it like this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { // JavaScript
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      { // SCSS Lint
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'stylelint'
      },
      { // SCSS
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
      }
    ]
  },
```

Unfortunately, it runs only once and then stays quiet. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { // JavaScript
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      { // SCSS
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!') + '!stylelint')
      }
    ]
  },
```